# How to prevent html page from refreshing while using onsubmit to call a function

Tags: javascript, php, html, innerhtml, onsubmit

I've created a simple quiz containing 20 or so words with forms next to each word for the user to submit their answer.  I use a for loop to go through an array that has all the words to be shown to the user.  When a user presses enter, I want each form to get checkAnswers(index) (which returns false) called so that I can use innerHTML to replace the label "answer" with "incorrect" or "correct".  However every time enter is pressed, the page refreshes, all text inputted is deleted, and the innerHTML does not occur.  I have determined that it is the innerHTML line where the crash occurs, but I am not sure why.

```
 //This works totally fine:
 document.getElementById("answer"+index);
 //But add an innerHTML and nothing works:
 document.getElementById("answer"+index).innerHTML("incorrect");

<? for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($array); $ii++) { ?>
    <tr>
    <td valign = "top">
        <? echo $array[$ii] ?>
    </td>

    <td valign = "bottom">
        <form method = "post" onsubmit="return checkAnswers(<?echo $ii?>)">
            <input type="hidden" id="english<? echo $ii ?>" />
            <input name ="<? echo "input".$ii ?>"/>
        <label id="answer<? echo $count ?>" />
        </form>
    </td>
    </tr>   
<? } ?>
```

Comment: Try to change onsubmit="return checkAnswers(<?echo $ii?>)" to   onsubmit="return false",If this worked,it means something was wrong with your javascript code.     <br> Also,can you show your js code?

Comment: try <div></div> instead of <label> I think there is no </label> may be the problem

Comment: would you mind posting code of js function as well i.e. checkAnswers?